# Adding a HTML mapped image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, mapping

I'm new, after a lot of searching I haven't found an answer so thought I'd post.

I'm making a website which requires the same HTML through each page, but also requires different style sheets to be used on button clicks.

So, for one of these "skins" I'm making, I've been having some navigation troubles, which have been resolved with image mapping. Adding the HTML in for this would change the other skins, so I'm looking for some javascript to add this HTML on the button click.

So far, I've got this, which doesn't work!

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+= "<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027" src="http://butterybeast.hol.es/butterworldwithlabels.png" border="0" width="1037" height="753" orgWidth="1037" orgHeight="753" usemap="#image-maps-2016-05-29-194027" alt="" />
```

";

See it (not working) on my codepen (Although I can't see this link. Think I've broken that too... *sigh*): 
http://codepen.io/Puffincat/pen/VjwxXG

And for the reference of the whole website idea, as I probably didn't explain too well.... http://butterybeast.hol.es/button.html

I've been pulling my hair out trying to sort out the whole navigation issue. It's a nightmare! If there is a better solution to image mapping, I'm open for this! It's not my ideal solution, I wanted some animation on hover - but getting the image in the right place was not worth the effort.

Anyway, as it's my first post let me know if I've done anything wrong, blah blah... blah. I really appreciate this site a lot, I've got so many useful answers from it! Don't want to misuse it.

Thank you!

Comment: Can clearly see quotes mismatch in the syntax highlighter in the question code - html string. Use single quotes at each end of the string instead of doubles so the inner doubles stay matched. Or you have to escape all the ones inside which is more work than changing outers

Comment: Also in demo your string isn't all on one line so have to use string escape rules for line breaks or get all on one line or use newer ES6 backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript format should be

#### Option 1

Escape characters using `\` (backslash) inside the `" "` (double-quote)

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "<img id=\"Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027\" src=\"http://butterybeast.hol.es/butterworldwithlabels.png\" border=\"0\" width=\"1037\" height=\"753\" orgWidth=\"1037\" orgHeight=\"753\" usemap=\"#image-maps-2016-05-29-194027\" alt="" />\
<map name=\"image-maps-2016-05-29-194027\" id=\"ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027\">\
<area shape=\"rect\" coords=\"1035,751,1037,753\"/>\
<area alt="" title="" href=\"#\" shape=\"poly\" coords=\"16,314,225,94,289,166,68,382\" style=\"outline:none;\" target=\"_self\"     />\
<area alt="" title="" href=\"#\" shape=\"poly\" coords=\"390,102,643,35,662,117,402,174\" style=\"outline:none;\" target=\"_self\"     />\
<area alt="" title="" href=\"#\" shape=\"poly\" coords=\"735,60,1030,211,978,294,690,139\" style=\"outline:none;\" target=\"_self\"     /></map>";
```

#### Option 2

Use `" "` (double-quote) inside the `' '` (single-quote)

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += '<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027" src="http://butterybeast.hol.es/butterworldwithlabels.png" border="0" width="1037" height="753" orgWidth="1037" orgHeight="753" usemap="#image-maps-2016-05-29-194027" alt="" />\
<map name="image-maps-2016-05-29-194027" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027">\
<area shape="rect" coords="1035,751,1037,753"/>\
<area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="16,314,225,94,289,166,68,382" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />\
<area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="390,102,643,35,662,117,402,174" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />\
<area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="735,60,1030,211,978,294,690,139" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     /></map>';
```

#### Option 3

Use `' '` (single-quote) inside the `" "` (double-quote).
You can also omit `' '` (single-quote)

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "<img id='Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027' src='http://butterybeast.hol.es/butterworldwithlabels.png' border='0' width='1037' height='753' orgWidth='1037' orgHeight='753' usemap='#image-maps-2016-05-29-194027' alt='' />\
<map name='image-maps-2016-05-29-194027' id='ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2016-05-29-194027'>\
<area shape='rect' coords='1035,751,1037,753' />\
<area alt='' title='' href='#' shape='poly' coords='16,314,225,94,289,166,68,382' style='outline:none;' target='_self'     />\
<area alt='' title='' href='#' shape='poly' coords='390,102,643,35,662,117,402,174' style='outline:none;' target='_self'     />\
<area alt='' title='' href='#' shape='poly' coords='735,60,1030,211,978,294,690,139' style='outline:none;' target='_self'     /></map>";
```

I've added `\` (backslash) at the end of each line to stick all separated elements together.

Comment: Would help to provide an explanation since it all looks like a blob of red strings and a few words explaining various options would add clarity